# Como obter a contagem e os objetos com criteria jpa?

Tags: jpa, nhibernate, criteria

preciso fazer o retorno dos resultados de agrupamento e também do numero de cada item de uma consulta com criteria jpa.

```
public List<Dica> obterDicaPorUsuario(){
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder(); 
    final CriteriaQuery<Dica> cQuery = cb.createQuery(Dica.class);
    final Root<Dica> root = cQuery.from(Dica.class);

    List<Predicate> condicoes = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    Expression<Usuario> EpDescricao = root.get("usuario");

   cQuery.groupBy(root.get("usuario")); 
   cQuery.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.count(root.get("usuario"))));

    cQuery.select(root).where(condicoes.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

    List<Dica> list = getEntityManager().createQuery(cQuery).getResultList();
    for (Dica dica : list) {
        System.out.println(" - -  " +dica.getUsuario().getNome() );

    } 

    return list;

}
```

Esta agrupando perfeitamente, mas preciso retornar também o quanto de cada agrupamento foi feito. Se alguém souber uma forma melhor de fazer isso, agradeço.